# (OpenCV) Why does my while loop only run once when rescaling an image?

Tags: python

I want to rescale an image by a scale factor of 0.75 multiple times. After rescaling the image once, if the dimensions of the image don't meet the specific requirements, I want the image to rescale again by an incremented scale factor of 0.75. However, when I declare my condition to be met for the while-loop, the loop runs once and doesn't rescale the image again (even if it doesn't meet the condition).

I have tried nesting multiple while-loops but nothing seems to be working. The reason why I can't rescale the image perfectly on the first rescale is because I'm allowing the user to input there own images. Rescaling once can leave the image too large or too small to work with.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = input("Input File Name: ")

parsedImg = cv2.imread(image, 1)
imgHeight = int(parsedImg.shape[0])
imgWidth = int(parsedImg.shape[1])

while (imgWidth >= 814) and (imgHeight >= 611):
    scaledImg = cv2.resize(parsedImg, None, fx = 0.75, fy = 0.75)

    imgWidth = int(scaledImg.shape[1])
    imgHeight = int(scaledImg.shape[0])
    print(imgWidth, imgHeight)
```

I inputted an image called "test_img.png" with the dimensions of 888x888 (a square image) and I want it to fit in a rectangle of 814x611 (while still maintaining the same width to height ratio). The while-loop runs through once, printing `666 666` which is expected, but the condition for the `imgHeight >= 611` hasn't been met yet. Regardless of this, the while-loop doesn't run again and just moves on.

Comment: it works as expected..you have two conditions which need to be met in order for the loop to run. `0.75 * 888 = 666`, which means the first condition is violated and the loop will never run again. I don't understand what user input has to do with not doing a normal rescale operation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `(imgWidth >= 814) and (imgHeight >= 611)` which will evaluate to `false` if one of the conditions is not fullfilled anymore. From your description you want to have:

```
(imgWidth >= 814) or (imgHeight >= 611)
```

which will have your `while` loop run until both conditions are not fullfilled anymore

Additionally, you need to make sure that in the next iteration, the previously rescaled image will be used. So it could look something like this:

```
while (imgWidth >= 814) or (imgHeight >= 611):
    scaledImg = cv2.resize(parsedImg, None, fx = 0.75, fy = 0.75)

    imgWidth = int(scaledImg.shape[1])
    imgHeight = int(scaledImg.shape[0])
    print(imgWidth, imgHeight)
    parsedImg = scaledImg
```

or, even better, as you avoid only creating `scaledImg` in case you enter the `while` loop:

```
scaledImg = parsedImg
while (imgWidth >= 814) or (imgHeight >= 611):
    scaledImg = cv2.resize(scaledImg, None, fx = 0.75, fy = 0.75)

    imgWidth = int(scaledImg.shape[1])
    imgHeight = int(scaledImg.shape[0])
    print(imgWidth, imgHeight)
```

Comment: Unforetunately, that didn't work. It rescaled the image once and then printed ```666 666``` infinitely.

Comment: You also need to add `parsedImg=scaledImg` at the end of the loop, otherwise it will always rescale the original image again